# Shortcut to duplicate line in SQL Server Studio Management?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

In Netbeans and Eclipse you can hit CTRL + Shift + Down (i think thats netbeans) and it will duplicate a line of code. Is that possible in SQL Server Management Studio? This is running with SQL Server 2008

Comment: Home, Shift+down, Ctrl+c, Ctrl+vv... How often do you do this?

Comment: Note that in SSMS 18 Preview 4, the default binding was changed to allow CTRL+D to Duplicate lines, quoting (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896594)as a the motivation.  That generated a negative response from users expecting CTRL+D to set `ResultsToGrid` so Microsoft has declined the request to bind CTRL+D to 
duplicate a line.[35544754-restore-ctrl-d-shortcut-for-resultstogrid-in-ssms](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35544754)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I think you can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> without any text selected and you can duplicate the line below it.

Edit: works in SSMS18

Comment: Yes. You can. The amount of times I've done this by accident instead of pressing `CTRL+V`...

Comment: Confirmed that just Ctrl+C with no text selected copies the whole line.

Comment: +1 - CTRL+C without highlighting anything copies the entire line

Comment: Ah I've fubared this but never realised actual key combo +1

Comment: By the way just `CTRL+C` then `CTRL+V` works. No need to hit enter.

Comment: This is not actually an exact implementation of CTRL+D.  A true implementation will duplicate all selected lines WITHOUT altering what was already on the clipboard.  CTRL+C plus CTRL+V clobbers the clipboard, so I would not consider this to address the OP's goal at all.

Answer (score 38):

If you're using SSMS 18.0 or above and don't use the shortcut for [Results to Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/database-engine-query-editor-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver15#results-to-grid-using-the-editor-toolbar) (which currently occupies <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>), then you can update the key bindings in the Options menu.

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options** -> **Environment** -> **Keyboard**
2. Under *Show commands containing*, search for `Edit.Duplicate`

[image: Keyboard section of Options dialog box in SSMS showing Edit.Duplicate]

3. Select the *Press shortcut keys* box and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
4. Now search for `Query.ResultstoGrid`
5. Remove both of the shortcuts for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

When you click "OK" to leave Options, you should find that you can use the key binding straight away.

**Edit:** Added confirmation that this is only supported from SSMS 18.0 onwards (h/t @Darrin for confirming)

Comment: I don't have Edit.Duplicate in my commands. SQL Server Management Studio v17.3. What version are you seeing this in?

Comment: @MattKemp I'm on version 18.1 now, but I think I was on 18.0 when I wrote that.

Comment: thanks I’ll update and try again. Will be nice to have this working properly

Comment: @MattKemp Definitely - I rely on key bindings like this and move line up/down now that I have them.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer

Comment: NOTE: Edit.Duplicate does not exist in SSMS prior to version 18.0.  All earlier versions will require implementing some kind of recorded macro such as using an AutoHotKey script in other answers here.  I vote for @Ben's answer as the best, due to using clipboardall and clipwait, but I have not tested that exact solution myself. See: www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Comment: @Darrin - thank you for confirming this. I've added a note at the start of the answer to clarify the supported versions.

Comment: Result to Grid link is a 404.

Comment: Thank you, @mmcglynn. I couldn't find an archived version of the page I'd used, so I've replaced the link with another that has (unfortunately slightly less) information about "Results to Grid".

Comment: Being a long time user of Atom text editor, I’ve got used to using ctrl-shift-D (actually cmd-shift-D on my Mac), so that’s what I used for SSMS, leaving ctrl-D intact.

Comment: I might also add that I often need to use `ctrl-D` to switch to Grid Results after inadvertently typing `ctrl-T` (Text Results), which in a web browser means new Tab. One of the problems with too many shortcut keys is that a typo always has awkward consequences.

Comment: That's a good point. My current setup tends to have it on `CTRL+ALT+D` for the exact reason you give.

Answer (score 3):

I use this [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to replicate the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> "duplicate line" functionality I'm used to from Visual Studio:

```
; make ctrl+d duplicate line in SQL
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
^d::    
    ; save clipboard
    SavedClipboard = %clipboard%
    Send {Home}
    Send +{End}
    Send ^c
    ClipWait
    Send {End}
    Send {Enter}
    Send ^v
    clipboard = %SavedClipboard%
    return
```

Comment: It's great that this is designed to preserve the clipboard.  I have had mixed results at it being consistent.  It sometimes pastes in what is in the clipboard, and sometimes overwrites what is in the clipboard.  I wrote my own CTRL+D AutoHotkey that includes some `Sleep` statements to give it time to catch up.  I would share my code here but it is full of comments of various methods I have attempted that also aren't consistent.  I'd like to know if anyone has a solid solution that works in many environments.  I use my version of the CTRL+D macro in 20 applications.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean about it being a bit flaky, wait times is probably the answer. Paste your solution with all the mess as an answer and I’ll be happy to try some things from it and see if we can make it better. Regarding more programs, CTRL+D is popular so I opted to only operate in SMS, but you could always make it global and exclude windows with a certain name

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is flaky.  I'll post my code as an answer and hopefully we can get some feedback to make it robust.

Comment: The flakiness is explained in online help. If anyone lands here and is using an AutoHotKey solution, you should refer to the example of accomplishing the OPs exact goal here:  www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Answer (score 3):

I like @Matt Kemp's [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script solution, but I used this script instead:

```
; make ctrl+d duplicate line in SQL
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
^d::    
    ; save clipboard
    Send ^c
    ClipWait
    Send ^v
    Send ^v
    return
```

Comment: This answer has a comment in it that suggests it saves the clipboard but it does not do it.  Preserving the clipboard contents during duplication is expected since that 's how it works in other applications.

Comment: This solution clobbers the original clipboard contents.  CTRL+D never clobbers the clipboard.

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS 18.2 [edit.Duplicate] associated with [CTRL+E, V] and with [CTRL+D]. The easiest way is just remove association [CTRL+D] with [Query.ResultstoGrid]. Then this will state only for [edit.Duplicate]. After that you can use [CTRL+D] for duplicating rows. 
I think it is not often case when you change saving result into grid or into file.
[image: Option]

Comment: Absolutely the easiest and best solution for SSMS version 18.0 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of an [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script to allow **CTRL+D** to duplicate the current line without altering the clipboard.  My first exposure to this hotkey was in Notepad++ and it grew on me.  A common use case is wanting to alter a line of text with a value in my clipboard, but I first want to make a copy of the line as a backup I can comment out.

This answer is similar to the one by @Matt Kemp, but as noted in the comments, there is some flakiness in what appears to be a simple script.

My answer has these differences:

- It contains `sleep` delays that give it more consistent results.
- I have set up my script so it can support a group of applications, like SSMS, VBA, OneNote, and even a coding website like JSFiddle.
- The cursor ends up at the beginning of the line instead of the end.  This is helpful if you intend to comment the duplicated line.
- I left comments in my script to help debug it and let you see some of the history I have toying with it.

There are two flaky issues that I am trying to overcome by adding `sleep` statements.  On occasion, when it saves the current clipboard into a variable, it actually saves the current line into the variable, resulting in never restoring the original clipboard contents.  On some other occasions, the value in the clipboard gets pasted on the screen instead of duplicating the current line.  I have hacked the script to add some delays that typically give me the result I'm looking for.  It's not as snappy as I'd like, but I'll take a little delay over inconsistent results.

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit on an i7 computer.

---

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; A window's title can contain WinTitle anywhere inside it to be a match.

```
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications  ; VBA
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio   ; SSMS (AHK must be running as Admin for this to work)
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, Microsoft Visual Studio                  ; Visual Studio
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, ahk_exe notepad.exe                      ; Notepad
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, ahk_class Framework::CFrame              ; OneNote
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, ahk_class ENSingleNoteView               ; EverNote view
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, JSFiddle                                 ; Website JSFiddle
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, ahk_class OMain                          ; Access
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, Advanced Editor                          ; Excel Power Query Advanced Editor 
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, ahk_class XBasicDlgBox                   ; Alpha Anywhere - Edit Event dialog box
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, [HTML Editor]                            ; Alpha Anywhere - HTML Editor
GroupAdd, ctrlD_group, [Code Editor]                            ; Alpha Anywhere - Code Editor


;=== Duplicate current line CTRL+D ===
; Applies to all application in the ctrlD_group
; Note that SetTitleMatchMode and GroupAdd have to be in the autoexecute section of the script (above first hotkey and/or return) 
#IfWinActive ahk_group ctrlD_group
^d::        ; CTRL+D
    ToolTip Duplicating current line...
    Temp:=ClipboardAll
    Clipboard = 
    SendInput {End}+{Home}
    Sleep, 50
    ;MsgBox,,, % "Selected text:" A_Tab gst() "`nClipboard:" A_Tab Clipboard
    SendInput ^c
    ClipWait, 1
    ;msgbox,,Before,% Clipboard ; This always shows the line to be duplicated even when the ^v pastes a different value.
    ;ClipWait, 2  ; This wasn't working consistently so I used Sleep instead.
    SendInput {End}{Enter}

; I tried to speed up the paste and  using ^v is faster but occasionally 
; would paste what was in the clipboard instead of the current row.  
; I decided to deal with it for now.  
; Removing SetKeyDelay, -1 may be the trick to having it work.

    ;SendRaw %Clipboard%  ; This works but is slow drawing on the screen.

    Sleep, 400
    SendInput, ^v{Home} ;paste plain text
    Sleep, 50   

    SendInput, {Home}
    Clipboard:=Temp     ; Restore the clipboard
    ;msgbox,,After,% Clipboard

    SoundBeep 300, 150 ; Let me know the ahk script is working and that the application CTRL+D has been overridden.
    ToolTip
Return
#IfWinActive
```

---

I feel like I need to tweak this code every so often because I'm noticing it acting flaky in some application.  Please chime in if you have a tested improvement that can be made.

[autohotkey](/questions/tagged/autohotkey) [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)

Comment: IMHO, this is the BEST answer.  Main two reasons, the flakiness of other solutions is due to not using clipwait and clipboardall.  If anyone lands here and is using an AutoHotKey solution, you should refer to the example of accomplishing the OPs exact goal which includes [from an AutoHotKey developer forum] in the online help here: ;-) www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Answer (score 0):

For SSMS 18 press Ctrl + E, V

It's a shortcut by default.
See the screenshot below:

[image]